# Bootstrap nav pills- first nav pill data still there when 2nd nav pill active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, nav-pills

I am using Bootstrap pills for toggling on the same page. There are two nav-pills  and two divs corresponding to each of them.I have constructed the first div correctly and is working fine. But when I am trying to construct the second div, the contents of the first div are hindering in the construction of  the second div. For ex: the col-* classes not working properly. In short the data of the first div, although invisible, is still there when I am on the second page.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills container-fluid" style = "margin-left:10px;">
  <li class="active"><a href="#homeTab" data-toggle = "pill">Download Data</a></li>
  <li><a href="#metaTab" data-toggle = "pill">Metadata</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container-fluid tab-content fade in active" id = "homeTab">
 ....    
</div>

<div class="container-fluid tab-content fade" id = "metaTab">
 ....    
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the answer.... Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing **tab-content** class. It should be wrapped around all tabs, and tabs should have **tab-pane** class instead, like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills container-fluid" style = "margin-left:10px;">
  <li class="active"><a href="#homeTab" data-toggle = "pill">Download Data</a></li>
  <li><a href="#metaTab" data-toggle = "pill">Metadata</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="container-fluid tab-pane fade in active" id = "homeTab">
    ...tab 1 content...
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="container-fluid tab-pane fade" id = "metaTab">
    ...tab 2 content...    
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is more about tabs in bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: Thanks a lot Marek Kus !! Worked perfectly. I thought without using tabpanel we could use that.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include bootstrap.js

```css
.tab-pane{
  position:absolute;
  top 200px;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="nav nav-pills container-fluid" style = "margin-left:10px;">
  <li><a href="#homeTab" data-toggle = "pill">Download Data</a></li>
  <li><a href="#metaTab" data-toggle = "pill">Metadata</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id = "homeTab">
 ....    FIRST
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id = "metaTab">
 ....    SECOND
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Tirthraj. But now only the pills are getting toggled. The divs stopped getting toggled.

Comment: Yeah that is the kind of thing I am getting. If you run the code you'll  notice first gets printed on top but "second" gets printed a line below and that is the exact problem I was facing

Comment: You have already marked the above answer correct @ShubhamGoyal You are done with the problem aren't you?

Comment: And I would be glad if I could get your vote-up.. @ShubhamGoyal

Comment: I would If I could. My reputation still 14. Still a Beginner. Sorry!

Comment: Now You can @ShubhamGoyal

Comment: I have no idea how that happened

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114700/discussion-between-tirthraj-barot-and-shubham-goyal).